# Calculate coverage rate of an OLS estimator

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I want to calculate the 95% coverage rate of an simple OLS estimator.
The (for me) tricky addition is that the independent variable has 91 values that i have to test against each other in order to see which value leads to the best estimate.
For each value of the independent variable i want to draw 1000 samples.

I tried looking up on the theory and also on multiple platforms such as stackoverflow, but i didn't manage to find an appropriate answer.

My biggest question is how to calculate a coverage rate for a 95% confidence interval.

I would deeply appreciate it, if you could provide me with some possibilities or insights.

Comment: which other sites did you search?

Comment: i found some posts here on stackoverflow, one on stack exchange and one on RPubs. But all of them differ too much from my problem, so that with my stats knowledge, i can't transform the ideas onto my problem.

Comment: Did you search stats.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: yes, and there i found the following post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540888/coverage-for-confidence-intervals

Comment: I just feel like this question is better asked there

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.